# Remove a firebase child if user is not active

Tags: android, firebase, android-activity, firebase-realtime-database

I have a user creating a game room in firebase. If another user join the game, everything is ok. My problem is that the "creator" maybe exit app, or close app, or is not in game when the other user joins. So i want in this case the game room get removed from firebase. I m doing it with the following code:

```
    public void removeGameFromWaitQueue() {
            DatabaseReference data = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("games").child(mCurrentGameKey);
            if (mCurrentGame.getState() == DatabaseModels.Game.State.JOINED.ordinal()){
//do nothing

            }
            else
                data.removeValue();
        }
```

My problem is that when i add the code in the onStop() and onDestroy(), of course the game get deleted, but even if another player joins the game and move to the game activity actually onStop() and onDestroy is called, so the game deleted again. Is there any other way to delete the game if the creator exit activity but not if the app goes to next activity?

EDIT

I changed the code a little bit like :

```
public void removeGameFromWaitQueue() {
        final DatabaseReference data = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("games").child(mCurrentGameKey);
        data.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    if (mCurrentGame.getState() == DatabaseModels.Game.State.OPEN.ordinal()){
                        data.removeValue();
                }
            }


                }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }

        });
```

This way as the mCurrentGame state is open i can delete the game. The problem now is that the if(snapshot.exists())not working as i get Null Exception after the game starts. Is something wrong with the code? Meaning the snapshot is checking mCurrentGame or am i wrong?

UPDATE

I manage to make code works as i need like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(mCurrentGame!=null) {
            removeGameFromWaitQueue();
        }
        // un-subscribe the listeners
        if (mCreatedGamesListener != null) {
            mGamesDatabaseRef.removeEventListener(mCreatedGamesListener);
        }
        if (mJoinedGamesListener != null) {
            mGamesDatabaseRef.removeEventListener(mJoinedGamesListener);
        }
    }
    public void removeGameFromWaitQueue() {
        final DatabaseReference data = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("games").child(mCurrentGameKey);
        data.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    mCurrentGame = snapshot.getValue(DatabaseModels.Game.class);
                    if (mCurrentGame.getState() == DatabaseModels.Game.State.OPEN.ordinal()){
                        data.removeValue();
                }

            }

                }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }

        });

    }
```

Its hard to predict every "unnormal" behavior from the user, so now my problem is that i need ALL this in an IF check that ALL the DatabaseReference data exists. As onStop() called in many cases, if my user comes in the activity but he is NOT creates a game, then DatabaseRerence is empty. So calling data throws exception. So how can i check if the DatabaseReference exists OR if has been created?

Comment: From what I understand of your question, you should just offer user a button to leave a game and in that button's `onClickListener()` implement the game deletion. Would this do for your app?

Comment: @PradyumanDixit  I dont want a button as i want to predict the unormlal user behavior, like create a multiplayer season and leave the app or playing in another part fo the app.